# How to get the y coordinate of the shared secret in elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman using openssl?

Tags: c++, openssl

I am using Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman to generate a shared secret. I require both the x and the y coordinates of the point generated as the shared secret (for reasons beyond my control) but the `EVP_PKEY_derive` function only returns the x coordinate. Is there a way to get both? I am using openssl 1.1.1 and cannot find anything in the docs on how to get the coordinates from the `EVP_PKEY_CTX`.

```
std::vector< uint8_t > sharedSecret( EVP_PKEY* privateKey, EVP_PKEY* peerKey )
{
    // Create the context for the shared secret derivation
    EVP_PKEY_CTX * sharedSecretCtx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new( privateKey, nullptr );
    if( !sharedSecretCtx )
    {
        return std::vector< uint8_t >();
    }
    if( 1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_init( sharedSecretCtx ) )
    {
        return std::vector< uint8_t >();
    }
    if( 1 != EVP_PKEY_derive_set_peer( sharedSecretCtx, peerKey ) )
    {
        return std::vector< uint8_t >();
    }

    // Get the shared secret.
    size_t secretLen;
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive( sharedSecretCtx, nullptr, &secretLen))
    {
        return std::vector< uint8_t >();
    }
    std::vector< uint8_t > sharedSecret( secretLen );
    if(1 != EVP_PKEY_derive( sharedSecretCtx, &sharedSecret[0], &secretLen ) )
    {
        return std::vector< uint8_t >();
    }

    return sharedSecret;
}
```